# PHP CURL 1 url, 2 responses

Tags: php, curl

I am working with a vendor's API. In the documentation they state:
"... will generate up to 2 response messages for each command. The first response will be an
acknowledgement message that indicates the message was received and parsed...
The second response will indicate the result of the command. Some commands may take a while to complete, so the manager should not expect an immediate response to commands. If an error occurred during the execution of the command, the response will contain an error message."

Is there a way to make cURL wait for a second response?

```
    $ch = curl_init('http://myserver.com');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=".$data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: plain/xml'));                                                                       

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Would it possible to tell us which API?  Also, what does `$result` contain?  Maybe the 2 messages are both in there?  I'm not sure how an API can return 2 responses otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't make sense at all, must be within the `$result`

Comment: No. HTTP will only ever generate *one* response per request. Either this API will include 2 API responses encapsulated in a single HTTP request, or they are expecting you to re-poll at an interval. Read their documentation. It is impossible to offer any more information than that because we have no idea what API you're dealing with and cannot look at their documentation.

Comment: What kind of communications does this API do? Doesn't sound like SOAP. Maybe you send a request and close the connection and the servers later connects to give the response?

Comment: It's the control API for a Cisco Media Processor. the only thing in the response is:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SpinnakerService xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <GUID>001</GUID>
  <Target />
  <Response />
</SpinnakerService>

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this was an error in what I was sending the API, not the response. I have fixed the XML structure and received an appropriate response. However, I still think the documentation is written poorly.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you will need to wait and check the same URL over and over until you get the data and not a status message.  Not very optimal.  Ideally they would let you pass a URL for them to POST back to when the result is ready.